# php mysql update if else returns true always

Tags: php

I have tried every example I could find to make this work correctly with no success. Seems easy enough, all i want is an error if the `$number` is not a value in the Tracking row.

```
<?php
mysql_connect("localhost", "user", "pass") or die("Connection Failed");
mysql_select_db("mydb") or die("Connection Failed");
$number = $_POST['number'];
$date = $_POST['datechange'];
$removed = $_POST['remover'];
$query = "UPDATE Custody SET DateOut = '$date' ,RemovedBy = '$removed' WHERE Tracking= '$number'";  
if (mysql_query($query)) {
    echo "updated";
} else {
    echo "fail";
}
?>
```

Comment: the question is not clear , what do you want exactly ?

Comment: Please take a look at this: http://bobby-tables.com/

Comment: I am expecting a result ( an error ) if the number from the input form is not in the Database. I ALWAYS get "updated" regardless of it being a value.

Comment: possible duplicate of [row(s) affected in mysql update with PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1487675/rows-affected-in-mysql-update-with-php)

Answer (score 1):

You're looking for [mysql_affected_rows()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-affected-rows.php). You can check it after your update and easily enough detect your error.

Regarding the actual code though, you should really heed the "suggested alternatives" section, [mysqli](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) are much more safe options for PHP database access these days. The code in the question has definite [SQL injection problems](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection).

Answer (score 1):

If what you want to know is if a row was modified use [mysql_affected_rows](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-affected-rows.php), that being said mysql_* functions are old and unmaintained you should use [msqli](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) instead with prepared statements as you are putting unsanitized data into you query